# How to remove VMware menu bar item?

Tags: macos, vmware

I have just bought a MacBook Pro yesterday. I have downloaded and installed VMware and Google Chrome. Today I see some sort of icon looks like a stretcher. That ask to search about any program but it doesn't show any thing after search. I can't remove that. :(

[image: VMWare Fusion Icon Statusbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware Fusion 3.x and later adds a new menu bar item that allows you to access Windows programs and documents quickly on your Mac. This menu bar item is available immediately after you install Fusion, and can be accessed even when Fusion is not running.

To modify the behavior of this feature:

1. Go to Virtual Machine > Settings.
2. Click Application Menu (Applications in Fusion 3).
3. From the 'Show applications menu' in menu bar drop-down, choose Always, Never, or Only when Fusion is running.